# Boundedness of a subset using linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $S$ be a subset of the $\mathbb K-$normed vector space $V$ such that
$$\sup_{x\in S}|T(x)|<\infty$$
for any $T\in\mathcal L(V,\mathbb K)$. Prove that $S$ is a limited subset of $V$.

> Hello everyone, I found this exercise but I can't have ideas to start with, I have assumed that $S$ is not bounded, therefore for all $M>0$ exists $x_0\in S$ such that $\|x_0\|_V>M$. Or I can say that there is a sequence that converges to infinity. But since $\sup_{x\in S}|T(x)|<\infty$, then there is a sub-succession $(x_{n_j})$ such that $T(x_{n_j})$ is convergent. Then I don't know what to do. Any ideas please. I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893539/boundedness-of-a-subset-using-boundedness-of-linear-functionals) but I don't understand it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an application of Uniform Boundeness Principle. On the Banach space $L(V,K)$ define  a family of continuous linear maps $\{F_x: x \in S\}$ by $F_x(T)=Tx$. Since $\sup \{|F_x(T)|: x \in S)\} <\infty$ for each fixed $T$ it follows by the theorem that $\sup \{|F_x(T)|: T \in L(V,K), \|T\|\leq 1, x \in S \} <\infty$. But $\sup \{|F_x(T)|: T \in L(V,K), \|T\|\leq 1 \}=\|x\|$.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right it is a direct application.